# Is it always valid C++ to compare a member function pointer with 0?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member, virtual-functions

In the following code, the assertion is not raised with the Visual Studio compiler, but it is raised when compiling for the iPhone using XCode:

```
class X
{
public:

 virtual void A() {}
};

X x;

void main()
{
 // Define a valid member function pointer to X::A.
 void (X::*p)() = &X::A;

 assert(p != 0);
}
```

Is this a bug in the compiler? How else can one check for a null pointer in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000977/iphone-assert-just-terminates-the-program

Comment: @Mahesh: I don't think that answers his question. He isn't saying that the `assert` is causing his program to terminate when compiling for the iPhone. He's asking why the assertion isn't raised under Visual Studio.

Comment: @Mahesh: The problem isn't in the behavior of assert, it's that the expression being tested is evaluated wrongly by the compiler.  `p != 0` must evaluate to true according to the standard.

Comment: `main` never ever returns `void`, always `int`.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question - you're not compiling as Release, are you?  Assert might be ifdef'd out if you are.

Comment: @Merlyn: `assert(true)` is a no-op in both debug and release modes.  The expression inside is true, guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, I meant `assert(false)` might change.  But you're right, it should be true.  I think I made the mistake when I read, "is this a bug in the compiler," by making an assumption that VS got it wrong.

Answer (score 10):

The code is correct, the compiler is out of compliance with the standard, which says (section `[expr.eq]`, using the wording from C++0x draft n3225, but it should be the same in other versions):

> any pointer to member can be compared to a null pointer constant

and

> If both operands are null, they compare equal.  Otherwise if only one is null, they compare unequal.

relevant definition of null pointer constant (section `[conv.ptr]`, the `std::nullptr_t` part is new in C++0x):

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

and (section `[expr.const]`):

> A constant expression is an integral constant expression if it is of integral or enumeration type.

NOTE: As an aside, the implementation-defined representation of pointer-to-virtual-member-function usually is an index into the virtual table, which would be 0 in the question. But according to the standard, the expression inside the assert isn't checking if the representation is zero, it's checking against a zero literal -- it is a null pointer check.

And the Apple compiler apparently mixed the two up. If you wanted to test if the representation is zero, you could write `assert((intptr_t)p != 0)` -- and that would be *completely* non-portable.

But **the code as written is perfectly portable, to any standard-compliant compiler, and will never assert**.

EDIT: And one more citation from the standard, which just repeats what we've already learned (section `[conv.mem]`):

> A null pointer constant (4.10) can be converted to a pointer to member type; the result is the *null member pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from any pointer to member not created from a null pointer constant.

Comment: But no one said that `NULL` has to be zero... right? So why is that legal?

Comment: NULL appears nowhere in the OPs code though, or in the quoted portions of the standard -- the standard does explicitly state that an integral constant that evaluates to zero (which was used in the OP's assert) will be converted to the null pointer constant, and that's what the standard is referring to here. Not the preprocessor macro NULL.

Comment: @Lambert: `NULL` expands to an *integral constant expression* that evaluates to 0; such an expression is called a *null pointer constant*. A null pointer constant can convert to any pointer type as the *null pointer value*, an implementation-defined pointer representation of "null" that is *distinct* from any other value (compares unequal). Two null pointer values compare equal. The previous is also true for member pointers: a null pointer constant can be converted to any member pointer type as the *null member pointer value*.

Comment: @GMan: I know that that's what effectively happens in every compiler, but is it actually defined in the C++ standard that `NULL == 0`?

Comment: Not sure what the standard says, but Stroustrup's seminal book The C++ Programming Language says, in section 5.1.1, that NULL is 0.

Comment: I think a pointer to virtual member have defined behaviour only when it is bounded

Comment: @Lambert: Yes, that's what everyone is trying to tell you.  I've quoted the relevant definitions from the standard in my edited answer.

Comment: @J-16: The standard says "any pointer to member".  "any" clearly includes pointer-to-members which are pointers to virtual member functions.

Comment: @Ben: But that's for C++0x, not C++. (I'm not saying it's not, I'm genuinely trying to make sure that the official C++ standard says this is true, because I read in a book that it doesn't have to be.)

Comment: @Lambert  It is defined that `NULL` and `0` are equal when casted to a pointer. And `NULL` is always compare equal to `0`. (it have some other gotcha, but they are unrelated to this issue)

Comment: @Lambert: literal `0` is a null pointer constant.  What the `NULL` macro evaluates to (usually `0` in C++ and `((void*)0)` in C) is irrelevant to this question.  The current ISO standard (commonly called C++03) isn't free, I choose to cite the one that is freely available to anyone who wants to study it.

Comment: @Ben: Huh, okay... but then, why does `NULL` even exist? Why not just `0`?

Comment: @Lambert: What part of my comment are you confused about? My previous comment is absolutely factual within the C++03 standard.

Comment: @Lambert: The C version (e.g. `((void*)0)`) may act differently in a variable length argument list.  But that's not portable, since `NULL` is often defined as simply `0`.  Many C++ experts, including Stroustrup IIRC, do just use `0` and forego the `NULL` macro.

Comment: @GMan: It wasn't your comment, it was your post that said C++0x, so I just wanted to make sure it's also true for C++.

Comment: @Ben: It's not that I haven't seen code that users `0` instead of `NULL`. But I'm just trying to differentiate between "all experts use it" and "it is guaranteed by the standard".

Comment: @Lambert: GMan didn't say anything about C++0x.  I did, and I also specifically told you where C++0x changed something (the new `std::nullptr_t` type).

Comment: @Ben: Huh, okay, funny my book was wrong. Do you happen to know if this was also true for in the C standard, or just C++? (Edit: @GMan: Sorry, I messed up you two when referring to the post.)

Comment: @Lambert: `0` is guaranteed by the C++ standards to be a *null pointer literal*.  `NULL` is not guaranteed, although by convention we make it the same.  For C, it's `(any_pointer_type)0` that is defined by the standard to be a *null pointer literal*, that's why the `NULL` macro is defined differently in C vs. C++.

Comment: @Ben: (edited) So the C standard differs from C++ in this respect... interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambert: [NULL is a symbolic constant](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Null-Pointer-Constant.html).  Why would you write `degrees = radians * 180 / PI;` instead of `degrees = radians * 57.295779513;` ?  Because it makes the meaning clear to readers.

Comment: @Ben: (I edited my last comment) Well, I always imagined that it was because `NULL` was always guaranteed to be an invalid pointer, and it just *happened* to be zero for most implementations, not that it was guaranteed.

Comment: @Lambert: And to add to that (@Ben's), over time many have found 0 to be clearer than `NULL`, especially since in C++ they evaluate to the same thing, and `NULL` doesn't actually have to do anything with pointers, per se. But since we *do* want to be able to specify the null pointer value directly, instead of through an integral constant expression (for overload resolution, for example), we introduced `nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your confirmation.

Comment: I'm looking at the [C++ standard](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf), and, doing a quick search for `NULL`, I can't find anywhere that it says that `NULL` has to be zero, just that `NULL` is implementation-defined. Can someone point me to the right page?

Comment: @Lambert: The null pointer *representation* isn't guaranteed to be zero.  e.g. `int z = 0; reinterpret_cast<void*>(z)` might not be a NULL pointer.  It's only *integral constant expressions* (usually literals) that invoke this rule in the standard.  The literal `0` is a standard way (guaranteed by the standard, that is) of using the implementation-specific null pointer representation is source code.

Comment: @Lambert: really?  Three times in my answer I gave you not only the quote, but also the section name.  Look at `[conv.ptr]`.  Page 60 in your version.

Comment: @Ben: Ohh... so you're saying that if you say `p != 0`, it might actually translate to `p != 1234` down the line, if that's the null pointer?

Comment: @Lambert: Almost.  `p != 0` in C++ source code might become `CMP p, #1234` in the resulting machine code.

Comment: In fact, the implementation-defined representation of pointer-to-virtual-member-function usually is an index into the virtual table, which would be 0 in the question.  But according to the standard, the expression inside the assert isn't checking if the representation is zero, it's checking against a zero literal -- that is a null pointer check.  And the Apple compiler apparently mixed the two up.  If you wanted to test if the representation is zero, you could write `assert((intptr_t)p != 0)` -- and that would be VERY non-portable

Comment: @Ben Voigt, c++ 1998 5.10 #2  ... Otherwise if either is a pointer to a virtual member function, the result is unspecified...

Comment: @J-16: Do you know what "otherwise" means?  This case clearly falls into one of the first two rules, which I quoted in my answer already.  Comparison with a null pointer never gets to the rule  you cited.

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone compiler gets it wrong.

Note that equality comparison *between* member function pointers that point to *virtual functions* produces unspecified result, i.e. this assertion

```
assert(&X::A == &X::A);
```

behaves unpredictably from the formal point of view.

But comparison of a member function pointers with *null-pointer constant* is strictly defined by the language. The pointer cannot be null in your example, so it shall not compare equal to a null-pointer constant.