# "Run > Stop on Objective-C exception" in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Maybe somebody knows where is the "Run > Stop on Objective-C exception" menu in Xcode 4? I've used it sometimes in Xcode 3, but it disappeared in the new IDE.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In the left side column of xcode 4:

1. tap on the breakpoint tab (the 6th
   tab over)
2. tap on the + button in the bottom
   left of the window
3. tap 'add exception breakpoint'
4. tap 'done' on the popup

Answer (score 49):

See the image It will help,

[image]

good luck,
Naveen Shan

Answer (score 7):

Someone else told me this, and I'm adding it here so I can favorite this question and have a useful reference to look back on.

> Set the objc exception breakpoint action to **po $eax** and you'll usually get the handy-dandy exception message right there in the debugger window when it breaks.

Comment: This is a great tip but $eax only works on the simulator (x86) code.  The register on the device (ARM) is different.

Comment: @jsd do you know what it is?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: if i'm understanding this article correctly, the register for ARM is either $r0 or $r1, depending on what threw the exception. http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html

Comment: more on this here, under "Printing CPU registers" http://nachbaur.com/blog/basics-xcode-debugging-tips