# Why would Xcode 4 not be breaking on exceptions?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, breakpoints

Just recently Xcode 4 has stopped breaking on exceptions. Every exception causes the debugger to stop at `UIApplicationMain` with no stack trace.

- I have a breakpoint set on `objc_exception_throw` (confirmed by GDB logs)
- Breakpoints are turned on (confirmed by GDB and other breakpoints work fine)
- LLVM GCC 4.2 is my compiler
- Enable Objective-C Exceptions is turned on

Are there any reasons breakpoints may not be working? Any flags I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried turning breakpoints on and off? I had that problem a few times in XCode3. Just switch them off, run app, then turn on again and it worked.

Comment: If that doesn't work, perhaps an upgrade to the latest XCode might fix it. No guarantee but I'd expect there to be a lot of bug fixes in it. :-)

Comment: @Derek This issue did cause me to upgrade from 4.0.1 to 4.0.2, but that didn't fix it. @Nick I've tried restarting Xcode and switching breakpoints on and off. *Mysterious*

Comment: Same thing happening to me (in 4.0.2), and Cmd+6 shows "All Objective-C Exceptions" is there and enabled. Switching breakpoints off/on doesn't help (plus other breakpoints do work - just not the Obj-C ones). Innnnteresting.

Comment: This thread may be relevant:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 4, you add the breakpoint for exceptions via breakpoint tab in the left (hit Apple+6).  You add the new exception with the little plus in the bottom left.

See: ["Run > Stop on Objective-C exception" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4)

For more instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work in XCode 4.2 for me. 
I solved my issue with specifying a sort of the exception as All C++ exceptions. Debugger is GDB.