# Xcode: debug unexpected iOS app crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm facing unexpected crashes of my app running on an iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1, the app crash without generating any error message nor crash log. I did also enabled zombies and tested with Instruments with no luck... how can I figure out where is the problem? I'm totally stuck :(

ps. I'm using ARC and my app is multi thread (NSOpertations + GCD)

Comment: There are some hints for catching the failure in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5).

Comment: thanks, could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(By popular demand:) There are some hints for catching the failure in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5).

Answer (score 2):

From the breakpoint-menu in Xcode, press the little '+' button at your window bottom left, and add an exception breakpoint. It will give you a heads up if the app throws an exception due to erroneous code.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow [this](http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/) url you will get trick to track the causes of crash.

Comment: Try not inserting links to an answer outside SE as they may stop working. Answers should be mostly self-contained.

Answer (score -1):

add some breakpoint before crashing point and add a lot of NSAssert to check your assertion.