# Log in with facebook in ios6 unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am getting the following error when i am working with facebook Login

Yes, It is a basic mistake "unrecognized selector sent to instance"  But i did not get where the mistake is

```
[UIStatusBar orientation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9a9c00
2012-11-23 11:15:46.854 Tattoo Later[1265:1cd03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIStatusBar orientation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9a9c00'
```

In this Method

```
- (void)loginToFacebook:(id) loginDelegate
{
fbServiceRequestingobj = loginDelegate;
 NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream",@"user_birthday",@"read_stream",@"user_about_me",@"offline_access",@"email",@"read_mailbox",@"user_about_me",nil];
 [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
}
```

App Crashes in this line `[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];`

In My project i intergrated "GPUImage" I am working on ios6

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be an error in memory management, did you try with [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)?

Comment: Yes, i tried as you said But i did not find where it is @zoul

Comment: Could you please provide more code? Where are you initializing your "facebook" variable?

Comment: I am doing this in "ViewDidLoad" like this  facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"172038482843979"]; @Dave

Comment: Maybe you can try to create a strong/retain property for this.

Comment: Try getting the exact exception trace as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5)...Then you'll be in a better position to tackle the problem.

Comment: What Facebook SDK are you using?? is it before SDK 3.0??

Comment: How to find the SDK? i do not know which SDK i am using the Facebook files from my previous project @Saliom

Comment: In Facebook.m 

static NSString* kSDKVersion = @"2";

Comment: I Tried as you said , Now My app not crashing but the log is like below     0   CoreFoundation                      0x02e9802e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02bfbe7e objc_exception_throw + 44
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x02f234bd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x02e87bbc ___forwarding___ + 588
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x02e8794e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
 5   Tattoo Later                        0x00052b00 -[FBDialog sizeToFitOrientation:] + 848 @tipycalFlow

Comment: i used strong property in my app @Dave

Comment: OK... It is SDKVersion -2 @Saliom

Comment: You might want to put a breakpoint in Facebook.m at line 144 and see if it crashes right after that one (might be called multiple times so keep looking until it crashes)

Comment: It is Crashing at this line  [_loginDialog show];  @Saliom

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19988/discussion-between-saliom-and-babul)

Comment: In `[_loginDialog show];`, go into the method definition of `show` and that'll lead you to the error. It might be because Apple has changed the way you handle orientations in iOS6. But when you get the exact error, you'll know the exact solution. You can also try posting it as a bug on FB connect's github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ios6 there is no method called [facebook authorise: delegate:] ...its just [Facebook authorise: ]

Comment: Yes, Its true.. Now i changed my code to ios6  Thank u @Divya

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to Facebook. **It's related to UIStatusBar and his orientation method**.

> `Please provide your source related to this issue.`

Comment: i am calling the method like this [appDelegate loginToFacebook:self]; i placed the calling method in AppDelegate . i think we do not have orientation code in AppDelegate But my app Crashes there @gonzaloaizpun