# Having error with iOS 6 when dealing with performSelector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

This is my code that convert a string to float

```
-(void) onUploadProgress:(id) sender valueString:(NSString *)valueString
{
    NSLog(@"Value String = %@", valueString);
    [progressbar setProgress:[valueString floatValue]];
}
```

This is the selector that call the function above

```
NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", ((float)totalBytesWritten/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite)];
[delegate performSelector:progressSelector withObject:(NSString*)valueString];
```

This code work on my iPad ios5 but when I tested on IOS 6 simulator , it throw me an exception `[controller floatValue]` unrecognized selector. I know it was caused by this but not sure why. It does have value in valueString variable.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What is the value of `progressSelector`?

Comment: Is the delegate meant to be calling this? and i dont see anything wrong, but the error sounds like a UIViewController is being put into its place, and they doesnt have a floatValue, so '[progressbar setProgress:[valueString floatValue]];' is the line getting the error, try making sure breakpoints are on in Xcode for "All Exceptions" and that could give you the line passing in the bad data.

Comment: I have put the breakpoint and error was located at the performSelector call. Funny thing is I checked with my mate phone with IOS 6, he managed to go through it without crashing.

Comment: What prints out for the NSLog of valueString?  (Presumably it's not a string in the failing case)

Comment: 0.6323 something like that in string format. then convert to float

Comment: Are you sure the exception is coming from the above floatValue invocation, and not from somewhere else?

Comment: You say the exception message is `[controller floatValue] unrecognized selector`, but that's not a message that would be displayed.  What is the precise message?

Comment: GalleryDetailViewController floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d89940'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c75052 0x2051d0a 0x1c76ced 0x1bdbf00 0x1bdbce2 0xc36c 0x1c76e72 0x7acd 0x1370742 0x136ee94 0x136feb7 0x136ee4f 0x136efd5 0x12e68a4 0x23e6a75 0x24a76ce 0x23d1298 0x24a716b 0x23d1137 0x1c4997f 0x1bacb73

Comment: OK, you've got a GalleryDetailViewController object somewhere.  And somehow it's having the "floatValue" method performed on it.  (And see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268397/581994) to get the exception trace printed.)

Comment: Hmm the second part of the code above is where the exception occurred. My iPad with IOS 5 works fine though.. only happen on the simulator at the moment. Try to update it to IOS 6 and see.

Comment: What do you mean by "second part", and how do you know the exception is from there?  Do you have an exception breakpoint set?

Comment: Is this 'progressSelector' a NSString? I think it should be [delegate performSelector:@selector(progressSelector)...], isn't it?

Comment: @Shinigamae - Presumably "progressSelector" is a selector variable set to `@selector(something:)`, where "something" is a method that eventually calls `onUploadProgress:valueString:`.  But it would be nice if the OP showed us that code.

Comment: Why do you have the cast of valueString to NSString in the last code line above if the value is declared as a NSString on the line immediately above that?  Leads one to suspect that valueString is not really an NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[delegate performSelector:@selector(progressSelector) withObject:(NSString*)valueString];
```

Comment: Oh I just tested ... I don't have that before hand.

Comment: No that doesn't work either... But my iPhone 5 and iPad 2 with iOS 6 works fine though... is there something wrong with simulator which causing that