# Xcode assertion failure messages do not show up in console log

Tags: objective-c, xcode, foundation, nsassert

I am using the latest Xcode, and have placed `NSAssert()` calls inside of my code. When one of the assertions fails, execution halts, and the console log states that an assertion error has occured, but the message in the `NSAssert()` call does not show up in the console log. For instance:

```
NSAssert( 1 != 1, @"Foo bar." );
```

Will not cause the message "Foo bar." to show up in the console log. It is my understanding that it should. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: :) Ok, your usage looks fine at this point. I'm confused, too.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268397/581994).  It's a bug in the simulator.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think assert failures throw an exception? in any case the proposed solution does not work for showing assert failure messages.

Comment: Pretty sure that an assert failure eventually turns into an exception.  Of course the other thing to do is to put a breakpoint in the exception handler -- Click "+" at the bottom of the breakpoint screen and select the option to enable exception breakpoints.