# Catch all exceptions so I can report them

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate

I want to be able to set a global function in my app delegate so I can log all uncaught exceptions.

Is there a way I can catch all uncaught exceptions, so I can log them to a file? I already have the file being created so I just need and way to call a method for unhandled exceptions.

Comment: See the technique used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268397/581994).  Just substitute your log mechanism for NSLog.  (But note that this will catch only NSExceptions, not C++ exceptions or "signals".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are some quick solutions to this (`NSUncaughtExceptionHandler` and the like), handling all the cases that you likely want to handle is quite complex. For instance, I assume you really want to catch crashes due to signals (SEGV), not just crashes due to ObjC exceptions.

IMO, this is not something you want to build from scratch. Use a framework designed for it. My favorite frameworks for solving this are [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) and [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/) (which uses PLCrashReporter).