# Unable to play a sound without errors

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I have been trying to find a solution to this issue. I have set up the AudioToolbox framework with a sound file correctly without any errors. It compiles and runs okay, but when I try to hit the button to play the sound, I get an ugly green highlight in a file called `main.m`.
Here is the `main.m` file it brought me up to after trying to play the sound:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

On the `return UIApplicationMain` line, that's where the green shows up. It says `Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT`.

What's wrong here?

Here are my ViewController .m and .h files:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize bannerIsVisible;


-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBanner" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
 }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, 460.0f);
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet       setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
[self.view addSubview:adView];
adView.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning


{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)cstring:(id)sender {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"CString", CFSTR    ("caf"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
@end
```

And now my .h:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <iAd/ADBannerView_Deprecated.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {


ADBannerView *adView;
BOOL bannerIsVisible;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;


- (IBAction)cstring:(id)sender;












@end
```

Comment: It means an objective-c exception occurred. This file is not the one with the problem, show us where you play the sound.

Comment: @j This question has nothing to do with Xcode. Xcode is the IDE you're programming in and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: I have added the .h and .m files to the main questi

Comment: This still isn't terribly useful.  We'll need the backtrace and message logged to the console to get any further with this.

Comment: @dandan78 - It has a little bit to do with Xcode -- Xcode often fails to identify the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the source of the error.  You can single step, or you can take at least one of these two steps:

1. Install [this patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12268397/581994) in your main, to log exceptions to the console.
2. On the Xcode breakpoint tab, at the bottom, press the "+" to add a new breakpoint and then select the option to add an exception breakpoint.  (I forget the exact words shown, but it's fairly obvious.)  This will cause a breakpoint when an exception occurs.