# Inserting NSNumber into NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

allTiles is an NSMutuableArray declared with a capacity of 9.  Next a loop inserts 9 NSNull objects with a method called `resetArray`.  I have a method called addToArray which accepts an NSNumber and index at which to insert the value at.

In another class I have `int currentTileValue = [self getTileValue];` which returns a tile value.  This value will be both the number into the array as well as the index.  Whenever I attempt to add to the array it crashes with no indication of why.

```
allTiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];
[self resetArray:allTiles];

- (void) resetArray:(NSMutableArray*) array {
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    [array insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:i];
}
}

- (void) addToArray:(NSNumber*)value :(int)index {
[allTiles insertObject: value atIndex:index];
}
//Different class
//Here is where I am trying to insert into the array.
[(BoxView *)self.superview addToArray:(NSNumber*)currentTileValue :currentTileValue];
```

What would be causing this to crash?

Comment: Note that the crash info in a situation like this is certainly available, you just don't know how to find it.  First off, add an exception breakpoint.  (Select the breakpoints view, press the "+" at the bottom and select to add an exception breakpoint.)  Next, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5).

Comment: I am most definitely a new Objective-C programmer, thank you for the information/question link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that `currentTitleValue` is an `int`. Given this, you need to change this line:

```
[(BoxView *)self.superview addToArray:(NSNumber*)currentTileValue :currentTileValue];
```

to:

```
[(BoxView *)self.superview addToArray:@(currentTileValue) :currentTileValue];
```

You can't cast an `int` to an `NSNumber` pointer. You need to convert it.

Also, your `addToArray` method is incorrect. Since you pre-populate the array with 9 `NSNull` objects, you need to call `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`, not `insertObject:atIndex` (this assumes you just want 9 values at all times):

```
[allTiles replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:value];
```

You should also rename your `addToArray::` method to something better:

```
- (void)addToArray:(NSNumber*)value index:(int)index {
```

Comment: Great response, thank you very much.  That also helped me with the expanding array question that I was going to ask next.
When you say to rename it to something better, what would be a better name for it?

Comment: Okay, I see the difference now.  What does that add to the method name?

Comment: Now you call it like this: `[(BoxView *)self.superview addToArray:@(currentTileValue) index:currentTileValue];`.