# Setting up a UITableView within a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a `ViewController` named QuickLookView and I need to implement a table view into it. I have declared the tableview in my header file:

```
@interface QuickLookView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
...
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *medTableView;
@end
```

In the `QuicklookView.m` I synthesized medTableView and added the standard `UITableView` methods:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSMutableArray * timeline =  [gCore getDosageContainer];

    return [timeline count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*         )indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"medicineCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [medTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier      forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSMutableArray * timeline =  [gCore getDosageContainer];

GuardianPatientDosageTimeline * d;

d = (GuardianPatientDosageTimeline *) [timeline objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
NSString *MedTimeLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f %@ of %@",d->amount,d->units,d-  >name];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:15];
cell.textLabel.text = MedTimeLine;//"toDoItem.itemName;



return cell;


}
```

This is how my delegate and datasource is hooked up:

**Outlets**

datasource------------------->QuickLook View

delegate--------------------->QuickLook View

**Referencing Outlets**

medTableView---------------->QuickLook View

(I would have posted a picture, but my reputation is not big enough...)

But I am still getting an error after trying a multitude of things. From replacing my `return [timeline count];` with a normal integer to linking things to who knows what. All the data in "timeline" and "gCore" is used outside of this file, so I know there is data in there.

Here is the error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint on "NSMutableArray * timeline =  [gCore getDosageContainer];" to see what the actual count is? Also it should be an NSArray as you are not modifying it. Actually, scratch that - you just need to do: "return [[gCore getDosageContainer] count];"

Comment: @Nick I just tried the "return [[gCore getDosageContainer] count];" and I got the same error message. I even get the error message when i change that section not "return 1;" for example. Which leads me to believe I have a problem with my delegation/datasourcing, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

In the Attributes Inspector for your table view, does it look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what mine looks like, just with the appropriate local names

Comment: Is there more to the error you get, such as "unrecognized selector sent to instance". If so, I would suggest you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350280/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-nscfstring-isdecompressing-unrecog and try some of the suggestions (exception breakpoint/turn in zombies)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove delegate and datasource outlets from interface builder, and set it programmatically

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //..
    self.tableView.delegate   = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

It seems that you connected that outlets to your view instead of view controller.

Comment: Nope, this did not work either. But I really do appreciate the attempt!

Comment: Are you sure that you removed delegate and datasource outlets from storyboard ?

Comment: Yes, I went ahead and pressed the little "x" next to the connections and both disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I accidentally placed two `UITableView`'s on top of each other in the rush of the layout. This explains why the `numberOfRowsInSection` was not being called - as it was referring to the secondary `UITableView` hidden under my main one. All of the the other methods above work for connecting a `UITableView` to a `UIViewController`, my problem specifically was just user error.