# UIImageView instantiation crashes in iOS 8 with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, ios8

I am receiving an "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS" error when I attempt to 
instantiate [anImage] in iOS8.

The same code works fine in iOS 7.1 and below.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

//In .h file:

```
UIImage *img;
```

//in .m file:

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *anImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

/*
 * Here is the stack Trace:
 */ 
-[__NSCFDictionary _isDecompressing]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e49740
2014-10-07 08:56:35.319 [AppName] [222:7088] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary _isDecompressing]: unrecognized 
selector sent to instance 0x16e49740'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x27e50e3f 0x35528c8b 0x27e56189 0x27e540a7 0x27d86208 0x2b2faf55 0x1011bb 0x103d27
0xfe759 0x1029d7 0x10060d 0x2b31fd4b 0x2b31fcf1 0x2b30a96b 0x2b32827f 0x2b2e45cd 
0x27e175cd 0x27e14c8b 0x27e15093 0x27d63621 0x27d63433 0x2f0d20a9 0x2b34e359 0xe9b05    
0x35aa8aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: code is working perfect in my app. just paste detail crash log. which can help more to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, @iphoneDev. I've included the stack trace. Also, what hardware and iOS version of iPhone are you running?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350280/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-nscfstring-isdecompressing-unrecog for hints.