# what does this objective-c error mean and/or how do i fix it

Tags: objective-c

im working on this project where i am trying to get a 4-4 red square to bounce around the screen but every time i run this code it gives a thread error that says
    Thread 1:signal SIGABRT
i am fairly new to objective-c can any one help me with what I am trying to do? here is my code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class home;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    ViewController* home;
    CGFloat rhx;
    CGFloat rhy;
    CGFloat red_direction_x;
    CGFloat red_direction_y;
}

@property CGFloat rhx;
@property CGFloat rhy;
@property CGFloat red_direction_x;
@property CGFloat red_direction_y;
@property ViewController* home;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize rhx,rhy, red_direction_x, red_direction_y, home;

-(void)event:(NSTimer*)timername{
    UIView* redhead = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rhx, rhy, 4, 4)];
    redhead.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:redhead];
    if (rhx >= self.view.bounds.size.width) {
        red_direction_x = -4;
    } else if (rhx <= 0) {
        red_direction_x = 4;
    }

    if (rhy <= 0) {
        red_direction_y = 4;
    } else if (rhy >= self.view.bounds.size.height) {
        red_direction_y = -4;
    }

    rhx += red_direction_x;
    rhy += red_direction_y;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.home = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    red_direction_x = 4;
    red_direction_y = -4;
    rhx = 4;
    rhy = 4;

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                 target:self
                                 selector:@selector(event)
                                 userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is not an Xcode question. BTW, are there any additional error messages? Such as one generated by `NSException`? Read and understand them, but at least post them here.

Comment: First off, in the left-hand column of Xcode click the sort of right-pointing arrow icon near the top to bring up the breakpoint menu.  Then press the `+` button near the bottom to add a breakpoint.  Select "all exceptions" for the breakpoint type.  Also, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268397/581994) to add an automatic exception log.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Actually, it *is* an Xcode question, to the extent that it involves learning how to debug using Xcode.

Comment: @HotLicks Not sure I get that. It's just `lldb`...

Comment: @H2CO3 -- Xcode is the IDE.  lldb is the default debugger that you get when using the Xcode IDE.  The controls for debugging are managed via Xcode.  It's really straining credulity to say this is not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, go to the Breakpoint Navigator, and add All Exceptions. It will breakpoint at your code at where it finds an exception.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One obvious bug in the code is that you setup the timer with a selector of `event` but you don't have a method named `event`. Instead, you have a method named `event:`. The colon make all the difference in the world.

Change your timer so the selector parameter is passed `@selector(event:)`.

As a side note, your `event:` method will keep adding a new subview. I don't know what your goal is but you might just want to move the one existing view.