# App keeps crashing even though removed error

Tags: ios, runtime-error, nib

I am creating a simple iOS app, and everything has been going fine until one error and the simulator crashed. I removed the error, yet the program continues to crash, halting at these two breakpoints:

```
//in my view controller's 'initWithNibName'
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
```

and

```
//in my AppDelegate's 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'
RSViewController *newView = [[RSViewController alloc]init];
```

I have tried everything, even deleted and recreating the xib files. 
The only thing that seems to work is literally rewriting it in a new project with the code. Is there a way around this? This is literally the 5th time i have had to do this and I'm getting very frustrated. :(

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing a `clean` on the project?

Comment: (And it would be useful to tell us what exception is being thrown.)

Comment: Yes I've done a clean, removed autolayout, and closed and reopened xcode. Sadly nothing :(

Comment: I tried adding a breakpoint I'm not sure how to find it, nothing is output to the debug window(I'm new to XCode, especially XCode5)

Comment: Do you have a rebuild-all option that you can execute after clean?  I wasn't sure if a clean by itself necessarily forced a complete rebuild.

Comment: I don't believe so. I did restart the simulator though which half-fixed it. There is still the first breakpoint though.

Comment: As asked earlier, what is the exception? Update your question with the complete error message. And note, Xcode is not crashing, your app is.

Comment: Please do Command+Shift+K once to clean the targets. Additionally, remove the derived data folder and then Run the project on simulator and if it still crashes then please share the crash log details.

Comment: How do I get the exception? Now it's just failing entirely..

Comment: What does failing entirely mean? Xcode itself crashes before it even gives you a compile error? If it does compile and run try this to get a break on exception: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: If all else fails, add the logic in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268397/581994) to your `main`, so that exceptions are reliably logged on the simulator.