# Xcode no longer displaying reasons for errors in the output in the debug area

Tags: xcode

I've been using Xcode for 3 years and whenever I have had a problem, such as an exception or unrecognized selector, its been very easy to see the culprit as Xcode displays the reason in the output.

However its no longer doing this, it seems to have stopped a few days ago, but I've not knowingly changed anything. Nor have I changed from running debug to release build for example, its the exact same project and I've not changed any settings of the project nor of Xcode.

How can I set it back to display useful information in the output window when there's an error?

(Xcode 5.0, output is set to "All Output")

Comment: There are several things going on here.  Often what has happened is that the system has stopped before it got around to printing the error message, so pressing the "run" button in the debugger window several times will often the message appear.  (Of course, when you do this you lose the context of the exception from the standpoint of observing variables, etc.)  There are other gotchas and solutions, more or less summarized [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5).

Comment: Yes I've quite often had to hit the run button a few times to make it appear in the past, but this time its having no effect. I'll read the link thanks.