# Adding UIImageView into NSArray crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsarray

I would like to know how to add a UIImageView into an NSArray without it crashing.

Currently I am doing this.

```
//.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *transButtonImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *transButtonImage;

//.m
@synthesize transButtonImageView;
@synthesize transButtonImage;

transButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"];
[transButtonImageView setImage:transButtonImage];

 NSMutableArray *arrayOfButtonImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayOfButtonImages addObject:transButtonImageView]; // this is where the error happens
```

When I try to add transButtonImageView to the NSArray if I look at the value of the imageView it's set at nil, even though I have added the image?

Comment: 1) You must know by now that you when posting a question about an error you need to post what the actual error is. 2) Have you verified whether `transButtonImageView` is `nil` or not?

Comment: Well when I say error, it just crashes the only reason I caught it because I used an All Exceptions breakpoint.. and it just shows the "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" where its crashing. I used poor wording sorry.

Comment: Did you ever create the image view? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Yeah, like @rdelmar said, you never initialized transButtonImageView, so you're adding "nil" to arrayOfButtonImages which should raise an NSInvalidArgumentException.

Comment: To see the error message, you must press "Continue" several times after hitting the initial exception breakpoint.  But before then you need to make note of where the exception occurred.  Or [add logic to your main to dump the exception stack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268397/581994).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no crash log, so the error may come from any where, but the following are the possible ones:

1. Does the UIImageView initialise? As we know, `nil` is equal to the `NSInteger` 0, is not an object, so when `nil` is added into any container, there will be a crash;
2. Is the container initialised with capacity? We can only add or remove object from Mutable containers, it must be a `NSMutableArray` with capacity.
3. May the image is too large, which hold a high memory, cause the memory warning.

You'd better try all the above. Good luck!

Comment: okay I am going to try using **transButtonImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:transButtonImage];**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an NSMutableArray to be able to modify it. You can then use [mutableArray copy] to copy it to an NSArray.

Comment: whops.. it is a NSMutableArray.. I used poor naming convention for it and just assumed it was an array. I have checked and its definatly a NSMutableArray.

Comment: Then we need to see more code, are you sure you have alloc/init it?