# Unrecognized Selector For Scene Transition Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Hey I'm new to Xcode so maybe this has a very easy fix and in that case I'm sorry but I've tried everything and looking online and nothing has worked so far. Basically I created a continueButton to transition to the next scene in the app once the level has been completed. Heres what its code looks like

```
UIButton *continueButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
continueButton.frame = CGRectMake(120, 150, 80, 44);
[continueButton setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[continueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SKTransition:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:continueButton];
```

Then I defined what happens when I click on the continueButton as this.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    SKAction *levelChange = [SKAction runBlock:^{

        SKTransition *doors = [SKTransition
                               doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:2];

        SKScene *Level2Scene  = [[Transition2Scene alloc]
                                 initWithSize:self.size];

        [self.view presentScene:Level2Scene transition:doors];
        [self runAction:levelChange];
    }];
}
```

However whenever I run that app and click on the continueButton I get this error.

> 2014-07-27 21:14:14.225 MazeGame[40846:60b] -[Level1Scene
>   SKTransition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14158670
>   (lldb)

at this point in the code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SpriteAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SpriteAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I don't exactly know what went wrong or what I should do and would really appreciate some help/advice thanks!

Comment: What it's saying is that you did a call of the method "SKTransition" against an object of class "Level1Scene", and that class does not have a method by that name.  If you look at the exception trace (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8100054/581994)) then you will see exactly where this call occurred.  Basically it means that you got the wrong object in a pointer somehow.

Comment: (Note that if the compiler was screaming at you about not finding an interface that contained the method "SKTransition" this is what it was trying to warn you about.)

Comment: add an exception breakpoint to see the exact line of code where the error occurs, without this breakpoint all errors will point at the line in main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the issue is this line:

```
[continueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SKTransition:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

It should be:

```
[continueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help!  That worked sorry that was a really obvious fix I feel dumb but I appreciate the help