# catch exceptions in iOS main Runloop

Tags: ios, exception, program-entry-point, runloop

UIApplication catch the exceptions in main run loop and rethrow it, for Mac, NSApplication has a reportException: which can get the NSException object, UIApplication does not provide this method. Is there similar thing which be used on iOS. 
the exception is caught by UIApplication and rethrow it, then it becomes a C++ exception. NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler can not catch it.

about reportException:, you can refer http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/7540-catching-exceptions-in-applications.html

Comment: You mean like as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12268397/581994)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No exception stack trace in console under Xcode 4.2/iOS 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5)