# All Exceptions breakpoint not finding "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, breakpoints

I am getting the following error:

```
[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I understand what the error means, but I am not able to find where it is coming from. Turning on the `All Exceptions` breakpoint is not helping, and it is not showing me what line and file the error is coming from. Normally it does.

**Wasted 4 hours trying manual breakpoints with no luck. Any idea how I can find this?**

Comment: Perhaps try commenting out blocks of code until you figure out which line(s) are responsible

Comment: @sddhhanover - Yeah, doing that, still is being elusive.

Comment: Can you share the suspected block of code?

Comment: @sddhhanover - It is too large and specific to my project.

Comment: No callstack information available?

Comment: Also maybe @try/catch blocks?

Comment: You could do a `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass[object class]])`on all the places where you use `object.length` or `[object length]` if there are not too many places like this...

Comment: @rokjarc - I am not using `object.length`, that is part of the confusion.

Comment: since you spent 4 hours I assume your project is big. I would suggest something like this: Create a category method for `NSNumber` call it `length`. Add this category to all files that you think might potentially cause it. Put a breakpoint in the implementation of length. Might work.

Comment: Auch, this probably means that there is a `NSCFNumber` (or `NSNumber`) in some payload dictionary under a key where receiver (library, framework) would expect a `NSString` (just a hunch). A lot of 3rd party code is checking for an existence of string with string.length (it will be zero for empty string or when it is nil).

Comment: lead_the_zeppelin's idea is great. you might want to add this category to -Prefix.pch

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin - Figured it out. The API I use was changed last night. A value that used to be a string was changed to a number. Guess I need to test for this in the future.

Comment: This question is very common and would not exist if your learnt how to debug code when you started programming.

Comment: @Andy - That is a rude response. I never said I didn't know how to debug, it was just a very tricky one to find.

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5) for some ideas on how to get the stack trace.

Comment: @NicHubbard it's not rude, this question with exactly the same crash pops up on SO twice a week at least. Stack trace and breakpoint is not tricky. This is what debugging is.

Comment: @Andy - The question was not about what the error was. It was about why the `All Exceptions` breakpoint was not finding the exception.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The API that I am using changed a string value to a number, so an `NSString` that I had for one of my objects was getting set to an `NSNumber` instead of a string. Then, later in my code that was trying to be set to a label. This caused the crash.