# [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance when moving through views

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, unrecognized-selector

I have encountered this error when i click on the label at the Master View that leads to the Detail view (which should show the labels as displayed in the data model at ReasonLibrary.

My code:

Master View Controller header

```
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *reasonLabelViews;

@end
```

Master View Controller implementation

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Reasons.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < self.reasonLabelViews.count; index++) {

        Reasons *reason = [[Reasons alloc] initWithIndex:index];

        UILabel *reasonLabelView = self.reasonLabelViews[index];

        reasonLabelView.text = reason.reasonsRazao;

    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    UILabel *reasonLabelView = (UILabel *)[sender view];

    if ([self.reasonLabelViews containsObject:reasonLabelView]) {
        NSUInteger index = [self.reasonLabelViews indexOfObject:reasonLabelView];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        detailViewController.reason = [[Reasons alloc] initWithIndex:index];
    }
}

- (IBAction)showReasonDetail:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showReasonDetail" sender:sender];
}



@end
```

Detail View Controller header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Reasons;

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Reasons *reason;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *reasonLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *motiveLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *zeroFiveLabel;

@end
```

Detail View Controller implementation

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Reasons.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.reason) {
        self.reasonLabel.text = self.reason.reasonsRazao;
        self.motiveLabel.text = self.reason.randomFact;
        self.zeroFiveLabel.text = self.reason.reasonsDeZeroACinco;
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

ReasonsLibrary header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


extern NSString *const kRazao;
extern NSString *const kMotivo;
extern NSString *const kDeZeroACinco;



@interface ReasonLibrary : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *library;

- (NSString *)randomFact;

@end
```

ReasonsLibrary implementation

```
#import "ReasonLibrary.h"

@implementation ReasonLibrary

NSString *const kRazao = @"razao";
NSString *const kMotivo = @"motivo";
NSString *const kDeZeroACinco = @"dezeroacinco";

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _library = @[@{kRazao: @"Razao 1",
                       kMotivo: @[@"Por que sim",@"Por que demais",@"Por que muito",@"Por que foda",@"Por que top",@"Por que demasiado"],
                       kDeZeroACinco: @"1",
                       },
                     @{kRazao: @"Razao 2",
                       kMotivo: @[@"Por que sim",@"Por que demais",@"Por que muito",@"Por que foda",@"Por que top",@"Por que demasiado"],
                       kDeZeroACinco: @"2",
                       },
                     @{kRazao: @"Razao 3",
                       kMotivo: @[@"Por que sim",@"Por que demais",@"Por que muito",@"Por que foda",@"Por que top",@"Por que demasiado"],
                       kDeZeroACinco: @"3",
                       },
                     @{kRazao: @"Razao 4",
                       kMotivo: @[@"Por que sim",@"Por que demais",@"Por que muito",@"Por que foda",@"Por que top",@"Por que demasiado"],
                       kDeZeroACinco: @"4",
                       },
                     @{kRazao: @"Razao 5",
                       kMotivo: @[@"Por que sim",@"Por que demais",@"Por que muito",@"Por que foda",@"Por que top",@"Por que demasiado"],
                       kDeZeroACinco: @"5",
                       },
                     @{kRazao: @"Razao 6",
                       kMotivo: @[@"Por que sim",@"Por que demais",@"Por que muito",@"Por que foda",@"Por que top",@"Por que demasiado"],
                       kDeZeroACinco: @"6",
                       }

                     ];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)randomFact {
int random = arc4random_uniform((int)self.library.count);
return [self.library objectAtIndex:random];
```

}
    @end

Reasons header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Reasons : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *reasonsRazao;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *reasonsMotivo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *reasonsDeZeroACinco;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *randomFact;

-(instancetype)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

Reasons implementation

```
#import "Reasons.h"
#import "ReasonLibrary.h"

@implementation Reasons

-(instancetype)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

    ReasonLibrary *reasonlibrary = [[ReasonLibrary alloc] init];
    NSArray *library = reasonlibrary.library;

    NSDictionary *reasonsDictionary = library[index];

    _reasonsRazao = [reasonsDictionary objectForKey:kRazao];
    _reasonsMotivo = [reasonsDictionary objectForKey:kMotivo];
    _reasonsDeZeroACinco = [ reasonsDictionary objectForKey:kDeZeroACinco];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Which line of code that produces this error?

Comment: @MahmoudAdam not sure how to check this :( Sorry im a newbie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object for key `kMotivo` is `NSArray` in your code. You are assigning it to `NSString` property and afterward to UILabel text property. `UILabel` tries to call length on `NSArray` and crash with an exception.

Something like following will work:

```
NSArray *motives = [reasonsDictionary objectForKey:kMotivo];
if (motives != nil && motives.count > 0) {
  int random = arc4random_uniform(motives.count);
  _reasonsMotivo = motives[random];
}
```

Code above will take first available motive from array and will assign it to a `_reasonsMotivo`. It should be inserted instead of following code line:

```
_reasonsMotivo = [reasonsDictionary objectForKey:kMotivo];
```

Comment: What do you recommend me to do?? Im kinda lost! I have tried to change the Object for kMotivo to NSArray but i get: "Incompatible pointer types initializing  'NSArray *' with an expression of type NSString

Comment: I am not really understand logic of your app. kMotivo is many string. Which of these Strings you want to assign to _reasonsMotivo ?

Comment: @user1370624 I updated with a replacement of code that you need to use

Comment: and where should i insert this?

Comment: @user1370624 insert this code block instead of your code line _reasonsMotivo = [reasonsDictionary objectForKey:kMotivo];

Comment: Thanks a lot for the patience, I managed to add few codes and the app is not crashing anymore. At the ReasonLibrary i inserted a function to get a randomFact at the Motive Array, and at the Display Viewer i call this function when i pass the index. However when i compile, the app is not showing anything, is just blank... any idea?

Comment: @user1370624 I have a bad imagination. Can you provide some updated source code and actually screenshot from an app to understand where and  what is not showing? Meanwhile Since we resolved the crash, can you set question as answered? Thanks.

Comment: You can find what the app does by clicking at: http://imgur.com/2yY9Ruc  I have inserted the following code: - (NSString *)randomFact; at ReasonsLibrary Header ////// - (NSString *)randomFact {
int random = arc4random_uniform((int)self.library.count);
return [self.library objectAtIndex:random]; at ReasonsLibrary Implementation //////  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *randomFact; at Reasons header //////// self.motiveLabel.text = self.reason.randomFact; at Detail View

Comment: Ok, and can you send somehow an updated code as well? You can do it as new question if you want.

Comment: I do not see where in your code you assign something to a randomFact in Reason. Likely this is the cause a problem.

Comment: I have created a method to give me a randomFact at the ReasonsLibrary Implementation. It returns a number (that should be the number of the corresponding item at the Motivo array). How can I use this number at the Detail View so I can get the corresponding item at the array Motivo to be shown?

Comment: It does not return number, it returns NSString in your code. I think you just need to focus a little bit on what you are writing. In other case it look like I am writing your app, not you are writing it. Crash is addressed, so no you can proceed further with an implementation of your logic. If you will face some problem not related to an application logic that only you know I would be happy to help.

Comment: Of course! You are right. Im new at this, sometimes I dont quite know what I get as returns. What I did was: at the Display View.m: self.motiveLabel.text = [self.reasonLibrary randomFact]; and declared at Display View.h `@class ReasonLibrary and `@property (strong, nonatomic) ReasonLibrary *reasonLibrary; Do you have an idea what am I missing here?

Comment: In implementation of RandomFact — [self.library objectAtIndex:random] returns Dictionary, not a String

Comment: Hmm... I see... Well thanks a lot for the help... Im completely stuck, this is an example after i completed a module of a course and I suddenly tried to combine several modules into this app, but i dont know now how can i get a random key for kMotivo :/ thanks tho

Comment: @user1370624 I updated my code sample, so it takes not an 0 element, but random one. If you would like to understand more about random functions in iOS I recommend to review following article — http://nshipster.com/random/

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually i just came here to tell you I tried really hard and managed to get it by myself, i have used at the Detail View:   self.motiveLabel.text = self.reason.reasonsMotivo[arc4random_uniform(5)];

Comment: I still have some doubts regarding Objective C, are you interested in maybe we arrange something like setting an 30 minute rate and you help me through Skype with some questions?

Comment: @user1370624 My Skype — epam.nikita.leonov

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
kMotivo: @[@"Por que sim",@"Por que demais",@"Por que muito",@"Por que foda",@"Por que top",@"Por que demasiado"]
```

use

```
kMotivo: [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chapter 1",@"Chapter 2",@"Chapter 3",@"Chapter 4",@"Chapter 5",nil]
```

Comment: why do you think it will help? Array initialized right with a literals.

Comment: i used it and it worked before. Did it help? if yes, can I get a vote?

Comment: Ok, I will ask differently. Why literal initialization of array is better in compare with the old style initialization of array that you proposed?

Comment: For some reason, when I passed an array that was not initialized like this, it would throw imcompatibility error because an array is just a pointer and NSArray or NSMutableArray are objects and it expects and object.

Comment: you are confusing C static arrays and ObjC literals for arrays. Each time when you see @ it means it is literal (syntactic sugared shortcut) for a definition of some specific object. While C arrays like following {0, 1, 2} for sure are not NSArray objects and will cause problems.

Comment: so as result your answer contains two logically identical definitions of array, but the second one proposed by you just longer.