# NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am using Flurry Analytics to track my app crashes and I keep running into this one:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument
```

What method in my app could be causing this?  Not sure which method I am using could throw this.

EDIT:
Here is the full crash report:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFNumber compare:]: nil argument
Msg: Crash! josh@robinruthusa.com ( 
    0 repziov2         0x000af2c1 repziov2 + 8897
    1 CoreFoundation   0x37450987 __handleUncaughtException + 74
    2 libobjc.A.dylib  0x3622f2d1 _objc_terminate + 128
```

Comment: Can you add the whole stack trace from the console? - EDIT wait, I just realised where you're getting this info from - I guess Flurry doesn't give you any more information than that one line?

Comment: Add a [breakpoint for all exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4), then post the minimal call stack.

Comment: @Joe - I don't think he's getting the exception in his dev environment - he's getting it reported out in the wild via Flurry which only reports the exception, not the stack trace / debug info etc :(

Comment: @deanWombourne thanks, so flurry does not offer anything else other than that message?

Comment: right, that is all I get so I didn't know if there was a common CoreFoundation method for numbers that threw that kind of an error so I knew where to start looking

Comment: You can try using [`atos`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) with address `0x000af2c1` and see if you get something useful (other than `main`) otherwise just check the crash reports that are uploaded to Apple.

Comment: no crash reports uploaded to Apple :(.  I'll try looking at atos