# Thread 1: Program received signal SIGABRT error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sigabrt

After XCode 4.2 installation my old app cannot be run. The build is successful but once simulator tries to run the app I get an error:

```
Thread 1: Program received signal SIGABRT
```

It points to this line in code in main function:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

No errors in the log other than:

```
(gdb)
```

Does it have to do with autoreleasepool in iOS 5? Where to look for an error? I doubt this is a code related issue because I was just running this app fine in older Xcode. This is an iPad app.

Comment: Try [creating an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build settings -> architectures

try to set the Valid architectures to armv6

i think it will help you

Comment: Valid architectures are set to "armv6 armv7". I tried changing Architectures to armv6 (currently "Standard (armv7)") but no success in running the app? Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Also, Architectures have only one default setting 'Standard (armv7)' so I added manually armv6 and armv7. Is this correct try? SHould I do it differently?

Answer (score 0):

Its not because of main function..
you check in GDB is there any unrecognized selector or memory leak issues..

Go to product button of xcode-->Edit scheme-->select  run (second cell of left hand side table) -->select Diagnostics--> Enable zombie objects....

After changing this setting clean and run your project you will the reason of crashing

Comment: Thank you. I just did it. But all outputs window does not show anything new other than what I described: (rdb). Good to know about this one though.

Comment: In addition, I just added return to viewDidLoad to make sure no methods are running and it's not code related, the error still occurred. So this is something within targets or settings. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an instance of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748425/xcode-4-2-sigabrt-error/9435143#9435143).  I.e., you have a simulator process that's wedged, and you need to reboot your machine to clear it out.