# PopOver from UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Here's my code

```
-(IBAction)showMenu:(id)sender
{   
    Demo   *mainMenuTableView = [[Demo alloc] init];
    UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:mainMenuTableView];
    [pop setDelegate:self];
```

}

Demo is my xib that contains a tableview controller stuff. This "Demo" works just fine as a fullscreen view.

I'm trying to create a popover with this view, but I've tried what I think is every other solutions on stackoverflow, but I still cannot determine how to create and call the popover...

I'm sure I'm like a line of code or two away... I hope. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Thx!

Answer (score 12):

After you create the popover controller, you have to tell it to present the popover.  You can use either `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` or `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:`.  For example, I assume that you have connected `showMenu:` as the action of a `UIButton`.  So you can add this at the end of `showMenu:`:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:button.bounds
    inView:button
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
    animated:YES];
```

You also need to put a reference to the popover controller in an instance variable or property.  Otherwise the popover controller will be deallocated when `showMenu:` returns, which will cause a crash.  Thanks to Floydian for pointing this out.

Comment: showMenu is in fact connected to the action of UIButton. I added the code as you posted it, and the app still crashes when I press the button. I also attempted it as this '[pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) inView:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
' but it also still crashes...

Comment: Without seeing the stack trace, we can't help you diagnose the problem.  Edit your question and paste in the stack trace.

Comment: 2012-01-21 01:15:01.049 App[21913:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'

Comment: That is not a stack trace.  You need to [set an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4).  Then when you get the exception, you need to copy the stack trace, **edit your question**, and paste the trace into your question.  Do not try to put the stack trace into a comment.

Comment: You need to have a UIPopoverController property on your .h file (instance var):  UIPopoverController *pop; and use it when presenting the popover...      pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:mainMenuTableView];

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain the "pop" variable! Just set a UIPopoverController "POV" as your property and use below code in your IBAction.

```
self.POV = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:mainMenuTableView];
[self.POV presentPopoverFromRect:button.bounds
inView:button
permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
animated:YES];
```