# Program received signal SIGABRT when presses Info Button on the application

Tags: iphone

when you receive this message **Program received signal SIGABRT** while pressing Info button on the application. Then how to figure out what is wrong and exactly where code is wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an exception breakpoint,.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7736927/451475) for a graphic illustration.

You might set a breakpoint in the UIApplication delegate methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

or

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```