# SIGABRT AND SIGTERM THREAD in all the programs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I use `Xcode 4.2` and I get 90% of the time this message:

```
@autoreleasepool 
{
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

> Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGABRT"

When it works and quit `iOS Simulator` I get :

> Thread!: program received signal SIGTERM

NOW ALL the programs (even simple tutorials with single sound button) that worked perfect before when I quit `Simulator` I get `SIGTERM` and when I try to run  again I get `SIGABRT`.
I am getting paranoidddddddddd.

> Error: unknown error code.
>   This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
>   (gdb)

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I would first try restarting your Mac. Sometimes Simulator can become 'stuck'. Just noticed AtkinsonCM's answer, That might work but restarting almost always works.

Comment: have you updated your simulator lately?

Comment: I haven't updated simulator, I installed Xcode mid December.I did reset content sand settings in simulator and many times restart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some things for you to try that have helped me in the past (in this order):

1. Product > Clean
2. Uninstall/delete your apps from your devices manually.
3. In iOS Simulator, iOS Simulator > "Reset Content and Settings".
4. Delete everything in your "Derived Data" for the projects causing the problems. (Screenshot) In Organizer > Projects.
5. Quit xCode.
6. Restart your machine.

[image]

I've noticed that Derived Data causes the most problems when you make multiple projects with the same name, wether it's on purpose, or by accident.

Edit: More details..

The only time I've ever gotten SIGTERM is when you run a test on a "device" and then quit the app from the device before you hit stop in xCode, then try and launch it again on the device. If it was more of a SIGABRT problem, I always check my IBOutlets. SIGABRT happens every time you delete the code for an outlet, but don't delete the connection in IB. [xcode 4.2.1]

Comment: Yeah, I have 3 projects with similar names (not the same) but with completely same actions, images and sounds. Should I delete the other 2 projects?

Comment: If they have different names, you should be ok. Can you clarify something for me. This is happening no matter what project you open, or on a specific project?

Comment: I had to reword my previous comment.

Comment: Today for a few minutes, happened in every project!

Comment: Now, it worked, then I quitted simulator and I got SIGTERM. When I opened the project I got SIGABRT. I did deleted the derived data.

Comment: OK, the only time I've ever gotten SIGTERM is when you run a test on a "device" and then quit the app from the device before you hit stop in xCode, then try and launch it again on the device. If it was more of a SIGABRT problem, I always check my IBOutlets. SIGABRT happens every time you delete the code for an outlet, but don't delete the connection in IB.

Comment: That's it!!! I was going to ask you. I have a button and by mistake instead of an action,  I created an outlet. But in Xcode 4.2 is not deleted automatically the connection? I have many buttons, I am going to check.

Comment: I had deleted the connection in IB. Has anything to do with the Table View Controller (I put 30 lines) or the view controller I deleted (with actions)

Comment: Your welcome! I would apreciate you marking my answer as correct if it solved your problem :) Thanks..

Comment: I am sorry but I can not vote up yet, it requires 15 reputation...Thanks  a lot!!!

Comment: This seems to have fixed my issue.  I am using Xcode 6.1.1.  Curious thing that happened after I did this, was that my application no longer compiled.  Had a missing semi-colon.  I have fixed a #define in a different file the other day, where I had put in a semi-colon by accident, yet didn't find the missing one in my class until after I did the steps above.  Seems like it might be worthwhile to do a clean, and also delete derived data once in a while.  Didn't know about cleaning up derived data till I came across this post.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The previous app is still 'stuck' in the simulator.  Try completely quitting the simulator, cleaning your project, then trying to build again.

Edit: A complete restart of your mac sounds like the next step.  In my experience this error has always had to do with an issue with the simulator, rather than the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

`SIGABRT` means that your program is throwing an exception.  If you don't explicitly set a breakpoint to trigger when the exception is thrown, then Xcode shows you the SIGABRT in `main`, which is useless for debugging.

You need to [add an exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4) so you can see where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Well I got:                                                     0_pthread_kill:                                      0x9bf079c6  <+0010>  jae    0x9bf079d6 <__pthread_kill+26>                       5 UIApplicationMain:                                               0x0030f855  <+0593>  mov    0x6165fa(%esi),%eax