# xCode 4.2 error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm getting this error when I try to load another view:

```
2012-02-21 20:31:38.477 App Demo[1671:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
```

I couldn't find where is the error exactly.

Any help?

update

```
NSString *pn1 = player1name.text;
NSString *pn2 = player2name.text;
NSString *pn3 = player3name.text;
NSString *pn4 = player4name.text;
NSString *k = kingdomLevel.text;

Kscores *kscores = [[Kscores alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
kscores.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:kscores animated:YES];


[[kscores player1name] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)pn1]];
[[kscores player2name] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)pn2]];
[[kscores player3name] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)pn3]];
[[kscores player4name] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)pn4]];
[[kscores king] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)k]];
```

breakpoint stopped at this code

```
[[kscores player1name] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)pn1]];
```

Comment: Click the Plus button in the lower left corner and select "Add Exception Breakpoint..."

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint, enable breakpoints and post the line of code that the exception is being thrown on. Instructions for adding the breakpoint are here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7736927/639668

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's the point of doing `stringWithString:`? You can just set it directly like `[[kscores player1name] setText:pn1];`

You're getting the error because `pn1` is nil, and you can't pass nil to `stringWithString:`.

Comment: thanx man that worked ,, sorry for the bad coding , i am new to coding

Answer (score 1):

That means that `pn1` is `nil` in the line:

```
[[kscores player1name] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)pn1]];
```

That means that `player1name` or `player1name.text` are `nil` in the line:

```
NSString *pn1 = player1name.text;
```

Comment: its not nil because there is some text in it, but now everything worked , thanks for helping :_)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a **nil** argument: `[[kscores player1name] setText:nil];` since `[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)pn1]` is **NULL**.

Instead, try this: `[[kscores player1name] setText: pn1]`