# CALayerInvalidGeometry'CALayerInvalidGeometry'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cloudmade, uitabview

I'm making a tabbed view application and using CloudMade's API.
I have a working project in a single view application which I try to copy to the tabbed view one.

I copied and pasted everything, set up the project preferences and everything.
The tabbed view FirstViewController is exactly the same as the older single view app.
How ever when I run the app, I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [inf inf; nan nan]'
```

I tried to google but nothing came up. It's my first tabbed view app so I'm not sure if there are stuff I need to pay attention to.
I'm not even sure what code section or error report to paste here.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks alot!

**EDIT 2:** Here's the exception stack trace (I think):

```
2012-02-28 23:51:00.720 ParkerAssistant[1454:f803] CRASH: CALayer bounds contains NaN: [inf inf; nan nan]
2012-02-28 23:51:00.725 ParkerAssistant[1454:f803] Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0156606e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01b1ad0a objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0150ea78 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0150e9e9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 57
    4   QuartzCore                          0x001df137 _ZN2CA5Layer10set_boundsERKNS_4RectEb + 215
    5   QuartzCore                          0x001d52fa -[CALayer setBounds:] + 156
    6   ParkerAssistant                     0x0003ee9a -[RMPath recalculateGeometry] + 927
    7   ParkerAssistant                     0x00002f55 -[ParkerAssistantFirstViewController viewDidLoad] + 1397
    8   UIKit                               0x003fd64e -[UIViewController view] + 184
    9   UIKit                               0x00418b89 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 105
    10  UIKit                               0x004189bd -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 63
    11  UIKit                               0x00416f8a -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 339
    12  UIKit                               0x00416e2f -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 169
    13  UIKit                               0x00414ffb -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 192
    14  UIKit                               0x0041585a -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 148
    15  UIKit                               0x003fefbf -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 158
    16  UIKit                               0x003ff21b -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 62
    17  UIKit                               0x004000f1 -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 253
    18  UIKit                               0x0036efec -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 592
    19  UIKit                               0x00374572 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 388
    20  UIKit                               0x0036e72b -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    21  UIKit                               0x0035dbc2 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 380
    22  UIKit                               0x0035dce2 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 280
    23  UIKit                               0x0035dea8 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    24  UIKit                               0x00364d9a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 35
    25  UIKit                               0x00335be6 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1820
    26  UIKit                               0x003368a6 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 508
    27  UIKit                               0x00345743 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1027
    28  UIKit                               0x003461f8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
    29  UIKit                               0x00339aa9 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x02398fa9 PurpleEventCallback + 1274
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0153a1c5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0149f022 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0149d90a __CFRunLoopRun + 2218
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0149cdb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0149cccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    36  UIKit                               0x003362a7 -[UIApplication _run] + 576
    37  UIKit                               0x00337a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
    38  ParkerAssistant                     0x000024e8 main + 152
    39  ParkerAssistant                     0x00002445 start + 53
)
2012-02-28 23:51:00.726 ParkerAssistant[1454:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [inf inf; nan nan]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1566052 0x1b1ad0a 0x150ea78 0x150e9e9 0x1df137 0x1d52fa 0x3ee9a 0x2f55 0x3fd64e 0x418b89 0x4189bd 0x416f8a 0x416e2f 0x414ffb 0x41585a 0x3fefbf 0x3ff21b 0x4000f1 0x36efec 0x374572 0x36e72b 0x35dbc2 0x35dce2 0x35dea8 0x364d9a 0x335be6 0x3368a6 0x345743 0x3461f8 0x339aa9 0x2398fa9 0x153a1c5 0x149f022 0x149d90a 0x149cdb4 0x149cccb 0x3362a7 0x337a9b 0x24e8 0x2445)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

**EDIT 3: viewDidLoad Method:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    id cmTilesource = [[RMCloudMadeMapSource alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"dfd3baf1ceda40ff8b4bf4b55303253d" styleNumber:1];
    [[RMMapContents alloc] initWithView:mapView tilesource: cmTilesource];
    tokenManager = [[TokenManager alloc] initWithApikey:@"dfd3baf1ceda40ff8b4bf4b55303253d"];
    _routingManager = [[CMRoutingManager alloc] initWithMapView:mapView tokenManager:tokenManager];

    _routingManager.delegate = self;

    int width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    int height = 64;
    _rifRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    _firCenter = CGPointMake(width/2,height/2);

    route = [[RMPath alloc] initForMap:mapView];

    route.lineColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    route.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    route.lineWidth = 5;
    route.scaleLineWidth = NO;

    _rif = [[CMRouteInfoView alloc] init:_rifRect :nil];
    _rif.center = _firCenter;
    _rif.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    _rif.delegate = self;
}
```

**EDIT** Hi, As it seems, the tabbed view controller has nothing to do with it.
I copied it again for a new single view application, and it doesn't work again.
I should probably mention (didn't think it made any difference before) that the working app does **NOT** use storyboard, just a single xib file. the 2 not working (tabbed and single view) **DOES**
I don't even know where to start..
Thanks

Comment: [Create an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4), then edit your question and paste in the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Edited. Hope that's what u ment.

Comment: Your second edit is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't link the map outlet, mapView, to the RMMapView object in the storyboard. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In your `-[ParkerAssistantFirstViewController viewDidLoad]` method, you send the `recalculateGeometry` message to an instance of `RMPath`.  `RMPath` then sets the bounds of a `CALayer`.

Looking at the exception message, we can see that `RMPath` is setting the bounds of the layer to the rectangle `[inf inf; nan nan]`.  The word `inf` is short for “infinity”, so your rectangle's origin is at infinity.  The word `nan` means “not-a-number”, so your rectangle's size is completely invalid.  That is what `CALayer` is complaining about.

Looking at the variables in your first edit, I see that `scale` is 0.  That is suspicious.  If that is the zoom factor of the view, then it's probably not valid.  If that is something you control, try setting it to 1 (or some other small positive number).

Comment: Thanks for looking. I don't have a variable called scale. maybe it's from the RMPath object.
also, RMPath.h doesnt have the method u stated... I'll edit the post with the viewDidLoad method

Comment: It seems to have something to do with storyboards.. see my edit plz! thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you linked the QuartzCore.framework? I'm pretty sure CALayer requires the QuartzCore. You can do this by selecting your Target --> Build Phases Tab -- Link Binary with Libraries. click the plus sign, and scroll down to the bottom and select QuartzCore to link it to your project.

[image: Linking quartzCore Framework]

[image]