# Ionic @autoreleasepool themeablebrowser error

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, exception, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic 3 application that requires themeablebrowser. Everything was working fine and the themeablebrowser was working. Now a bug happens but i don't know how. I am getting the error after adding and building the ios platform.

The themeablebrowser plugin is not working anymore and in Xcode I am getting this error:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");        
    return retVal;
}
```

the error here

```
   2017-09-21 03:22:53.022 toufoulakids[553:107535] -[CDVFileTransferDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:] [Line 637] File Transfer Download success

2017-09-21 03:22:53.216 toufoulakids[553:107195] -[__NSCFString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15537d60
2017-09-21 03:22:53.222 toufoulakids[553:107195] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSCFString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15537d60
```

Comment: Hi! The error you say you've posted above looks a lot like just code to me. I'm not sure if that code is even relevant, but you might at least want to post the error you're getting. Otherwise it will be very hard to provide any help.

Comment: alright here is a screenshot of the xCode error[link](http://hpics.li/865f010)

Comment: That's still not very informative, unfortunately. Try to follow the suggestions here to see if you can get some more information about the error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782776

Comment: i did that but it only shows Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6 ...

Comment: here is the error :D   [link](http://hpics.li/caff6d1)

Comment: Could you copy and paste the text of the error message into the question, or a new comment? It would make it much easier to identify the problem.

Comment: I have add the error code in the question .

Comment: Great, this is starting to look like an answerable question. I've made some tweaks to improve it, and now we just need to wait for someone who actually knows what they're doing :D

Comment: thanks for your help , i really appreciate that .