# xcode 4.2 soundboard thread 1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

hi i have created a Xcode soundboard but when i run it on my iPhone i get this error and not to sure how to solve it can you help ?

```
//
//  main.m
//  sound
//
//  Created by Paul masters on 27/04/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

the error is

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

thread 1: signal SIGABRT

THANKS

this is the view controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)yooo:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)boom:(id)sender;


@end
```

this is the view controller.m

```
- (IBAction)yooo:(id)sender {

    CFBundleRef mainbundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileUrlRef;
    soundFileUrlRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainbundle, (CFStringRef) @"tb1", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileUrlRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);}

- (IBAction)boom:(id)sender {


    CFBundleRef mainbundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileUrlRef;
    soundFileUrlRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainbundle, (CFStringRef) @"ta1", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL); 
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileUrlRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}


@end
```

this is my code with that thread 1 error!!
[image: here is a image of my code that failed]

[image]

Comment: i will post the code i have up i don't no if that will help but may as e

Comment: in the console (gdb or lldb) it will show what kind of exception is happening

Comment: sorry buddy wheres the console lol

Comment: menu View - Debug Area - Activate Console

Comment: yeah i just did that but it hasn't change anything?

Comment: all right, man, zip the project and upload it somewhere... I'll have a look at it.

Comment: sorry, buddy, but this is going no way... use google

Comment: why don't i just upload images of the code the view controller etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an exception breakpoint. See ["Run > Stop on Objective-C exception" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4). If you don't have an exception breakpoint and an exception occurs, all you will see is just a SIGABRT with no stack, so you can't find out, what really happened.

Comment: hi there this is a iPhone application i went on there and clicked on a few pages but i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: still stuck everyone please help

Comment: now you need to take a look at the stack trace, where the exception occurred, post it here including the message of the exception

Comment: return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
thread 1: breaking point 1.1 I'm so confused can you show me pictures again

Comment: why don't you take a screenshot and post it in your question?

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is locate build phases and then click + and add `audio.framework`
and then try to `run and build` and all should be good.