# Getting crash location in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am getting a crash in my application which I am not able to trace out. In the log I am getting :

> [CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xeb8a560

Even on debugging I could not trace out the crash. I placed breakpoints and enabled NSZombie but still not helpful. Does anyone have some idea for getting the location of crash?

Comment: Set MallocStackLogging, MallocStackLoggingNoCompact environments - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string object over released. You can create an exception break point to find where it crashes. Also you can try using `bt` in GDB to get crash log.

This [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) lots of tricks and tips.

Comment: Please explain your suggestions.

Comment: @Nitish You want me to explain how to create exception break point?.

Answer (score 2):

for getting the exact location of crash, you need to add 'Exception BreakPoint' , that will add breakpoint to exact location where the crash occurs.

In the left side column of xcode 4:

1. tap on the breakpoint tab (the 6th tab over)
2. tap on the + button in the bottom left of the window
3. tap 'add exception breakpoint'
4. tap 'done' on the popup

reference ["Run > Stop on Objective-C exception" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

This type of error (using class retain/release memory management) can also be debugged using the Zombies Instrument. Often (not always) you can see the history of where the deallocated object was retained/released and figure out why is vanished out from under you.