# Tabbarcontroller with navigation controller iphone application

Tags: iphone

i added a tabbarcontroller and inside that navigation controllers to a window in iphone application.its working fine.but when i added a button to one view ,and given an action to that button then the application is crashing.why?

Comment: check crash logs

see [Getting crash location ios][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612444/getting-crash-location-ios/10614106#10614106

Comment: it is giving SIGABRT from main()

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the action method in .m class.