# ios adding an object as subview and releazing give EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception , why?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, memory-management

I have a simple application where i add UIButton programmatically as follow

```
    for(int i=0;i<[self.contentList count];i++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelection:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button setTitle:[ [contentList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nameKey"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag=i+kButtonTagOffset;
        [self.view insertSubview:button atIndex:0];
       // [button release];

    }
```

Then Accessing it when view change its orientation as follow to adjust its position as follow

```
  for (int row = 0; row < Portrait_TILE_ROWS; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < Portrait_TILE_COLUMNS; ++col)
        {
            int index = (row * Portrait_TILE_COLUMNS) + col;
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(LandScape_TILE_MARGIN + col * (LandScape_TILE_MARGIN + LandScape_TILE_WIDTH),
                                      LandScape_TILE_MARGIN + row * (LandScape_TILE_MARGIN + LandScape_TILE_HEIGHT),
                                      LandScape_TILE_WIDTH, LandScape_TILE_HEIGHT);

            UIButton *tmb= (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:index+kButtonTagOffset];
            if([tmb isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) //isKindOfClass
            {   
                [  [self.view viewWithTag:index+kButtonTagOffset] setFrame:frame];

            }

        }
    }
```

My First question is why i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error if i release the UIBUtton after adding to subview and it only happens on the device not the simulator .I thought when adding to a subview the retain count of the objects goes up by one and accessing it later won't raise that ERROR any idea ?

How i can figure out within the xcode debugger what object and where that  EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception 
 is raised i figured it out by simply commenting parts of the code !!!

Thanks
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reread the basics of memory management and cocoa naming conventions.  You didn't call alloc, copy, or retain on it...so releasing it is incorrect.  That constructor returns an *autoreleased* object.  If this concept is difficult for you, please switch to ARC.

As for figuring out which line the error is on -> ["Run > Stop on Objective-C exception" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4)

Comment: I will for sure read the memory management again. If its an autorelased object and ADDED to NSArray or in my case as a subview wouldnt that subview retain it .  Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: Yes, it will, but then you release it so it gets deallocated -> +1 alloc, +1 retained by superview, -1 your release call, -1 autorelease later = 0 (deallocated, and any further use causes a crash)

Comment: got it , i really appreciate your patient with a new ios programmer . Thanks :)