# iphone: what this error is?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode4.2

I am new to iphone development and working on universal app, I just created some new fields on View and set its outlets with code in xCode 4.2.
Than I compile and this error came, do not know how to get rid of this error.

I also deleted some references to Xib fields.

How to know where is the buggy code or error.

please help

[image]

Edit:
I just Add Exception breakpoint in Breakpoint navigator and it showed this place of error.

[image]

Comment: Actually this is not error. your application has been crashed to get rid of this post your code when your app crash

Comment: Enable NSZombie in your project.. and you could see what the crash is using [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode).. you could share the error here.. which would help others to solve your issue

Comment: SIGABRT is the usual result of an assertion failure, or of direct calls to `abort()` or `std::terminate()`.

Comment: [Enable NSZombie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5387006/1603234)

Comment: sharing the error logs would help people to solve your issues

Comment: are you making MainWindow.xib

Comment: Posting the `Crash log` would bring you more answers :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its an Application crash which may be due to wrong referencing. Follow  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4), it will help you to get the error place.

Answer (score 0):

a `SIGABRT` error means one of MANY things. I'd recommend implimenting break points on all exceptions, as detailed in [this article](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

It can be that you send message to deallocated object. more likely you released your controls or views before viewDidUnload, or it can be that you using some properties or methods of viewController that had removed from window. There are plenty cases for this error.

Answer (score 0):

If there  is no window appeared before you get the exception then check out your xib connections.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an Error, its crash your application when u run this app.
Make sure that your all connection are proper or u use undefined symbol in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this very good article. Read it out, it will be helpful in the future.

This is a fantastic link, goto section "The Exception Breakpoint". This will answer your question.

[My app crashed, Now what?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)