# Error : "Range {2147483647, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1" while updating code from ios 5.x to 6.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am trying to update my application from ios5.x to 6.0.My code is running perfectly in ios 5.1.1 but when i run in ios6.0 i am getting error

`"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableIndexSet addIndexesInRange:]: Range {2147483647, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1'"`

on the click of button.
Please suggest any solution

Comment: ...have you looked at the backtrace? gdb? have you  tried to debug it and find out where the error is coming from?

Comment: use breakpoints and debug facility ...best of luck :)

Comment: I debug the code , but i am not getting how to resolve it.

Comment: I am using pickerview on the click of button,it crashes on the call of delegates of pickerview.

Comment: Your question reads like "Lights don't turn on in some rooms in my house. Can you tell me why?".  Post the code.  Post the backtraces of the crash. Post some context.   As it is, the solution will be *stop sending out of range ranges to something that takes ranges that aren't in that range*.

Comment: @L3ST3R The first thing you need to do is set an exception breakpoint.  [Look at this question for help setting an exception breakpoint.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4)  After you have set the exception breakpoint, run your app and trigger the bug.  Xcode will show the stack trace of the code that triggers the exception.  Copy the entire stack trace, edit your post here on stackoverflow, and paste in the stack trace.

Answer (score 5):

This one may be  Helps you ,in my case i'm also facing the same problem but now i got it, where i had done the mistake..
[UIPickerView selectrow crash in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538118/uipickerview-selectrow-crash-in-ios-6)