# CocosDenshion - CDAudioManager's load method fails

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play a background music for a scene of a game I am developing using Cocos2d 2.0

but the execution stops at

in CDAudioManager.m:

```
-(void) load:(NSString*) filePath {
    ........
    .........
    [[audioSourcePlayer prepareToPlay]; //This is where the execution stops!!
```

and it gives NO details about the exception!, it just breaks!

and this is how I am playing the music:

```
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background_music" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSLog(@"soundFile: %@", soundFile); //The path is correct
SimpleAudioEngine *sae = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine];
if (sae != nil) {
    [sae preloadBackgroundMusic:soundFile];
    if (sae.willPlayBackgroundMusic) {
        sae.backgroundMusicVolume = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

I am using Cocos2d 2.0, Xcode 4.5.1, iOS SDK 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file passes the exists test:

```
NSLog(@"soundFile: %@, exists: %u", 
      soundFile, [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:soundFile]);
```

exists will be 1 if the file exists.

If it does exists, step into preloadBackgroundMusic and see if there's anything returning nil. I could imagine that the mp3 uses a format that's not supported by CD. If so, use Audacity or similar audio tool to open and re-save the mp3 file.

You should also add the [add the global exception breakpoint in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4). That way Xcode doesn't just stop when an exception occurs but also jumps to the offending line.