# Settings default value to float variable

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm developing a location based app and I'm using the following code (which works perfectly) to retrieve the location of the user. However, I would like to set a default value to the longitude and latitude in case the user turned off location services.

I tried self.latitude = 0; but the app crashes. latitude and longitude are variables of type float. Ideally I want to set them to a default value of (0,0).

So basically: how can I set a default value for a variable of type `float`?

Thanks for your help.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation    *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    self.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    self.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    SVGeocoder *geocodeRequest = [[SVGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    [geocodeRequest setDelegate:self];
    [geocodeRequest startAsynchronous];
    //   NSLog(@"lat:%f,long:%f",self.latitude,self.longitude);

    [self.locationMgr stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: how did you define latitude and longitude?

Comment: What is the error message when the app crashes?

Comment: I defined latitude and longitude this way :float latitude;
    float longitude;

Comment: then remove the "self." in front of both.

Comment: @jimpic not if they're properties. but if they're simple ivars, yes.

Comment: @StefanyWilley You need to [set an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4) and trigger the crash.  Then copy the stack trace, edit your post, and paste it in.

Comment: Please refrain from using ALL CAPS in the future.

Comment: I tried removing the self it didn't work. Same error, I'm getting SIGABRT

Comment: Isn't there a simple way to set a default value for longitude and latitude?

Comment: The simple way is just to assign zero (or whatever default you want). If it didn't work, you need to post the code where you tried to set the default, and you need to post the stack trace of the crash, and you need to post any messages that showed up in the debug console.

Comment: i asume you have another error, nothing to do with latitude = 0;

Comment: in ARC, the default value should be 0 anyway.