# [__NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3141c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to get a search display controller working and have just got this error:

> 2012-11-30 14:48:19.903 searchstory[5812:c07] -[__NSCFConstantString
>   objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3141c
>   2012-11-30 14:48:19.904 searchstory[5812:c07] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x3141c'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1cc0012 0x10fde7e 0x1d4b4bd 0x1cafbbc 0x1caf94e 0x2901d 0xfff4b 0x10001f 0xe880b 0xe6ec2 0xf1d51 0xfa3ad
>   0x102454 0x329635 0x32c0de 0x27bd85 0x1111705 0x48873 0x10a2ce
>   0x109960 0x11678c 0x120bf6 0xbbedc9 0x1d1a0c5 0x1c74efa 0xaf3482
>   0x359509e 0x26e426a 0x2b1f78c 0x2b22588 0x356fd12 0x356fe4a 0x35705c0
>   0x35703b8 0x356f904 0x295eeab 0x295ee13 0x3542596 0x356ebcc 0x2b1cac6
>   0x2b1bd56 0x2b4f320 0x31a9afd 0x2b45e66 0x2b470aa 0x2b4501e 0x31a81aa
>   0x2b5f491 0x2b4f0ca 0x2b2303e 0x27207fb 0x11116b0 0x358aed0 0x275f384
>   0x27614df 0x206254 0x1c904f 0x1ca3b8 0x1c8f5e 0x1d312d 0x5643b
>   0x153e05 0x153e05 0x153e05 0x153e05 0x153e05 0x153e05 0x153e05
>   0x153e05 0x153e05 0x56495 0x55e66 0x5624b 0x47cf8 0x1c1bdf9 0x1c1bad0
>   0x1c35bf5 0x1c35962 0x1c66bb6 0x1c65f44 0x1c65e1b 0x1c1a7e3 0x1c1a668
>   0x4565c 0x1c8d 0x1bb5) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an
>   exception

I have been playing about with the code trying to get this to work. The code I have for the search and for the tablerow is:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    NSString *contentForThisRow = nil;

    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
        contentForThisRow = [[[[self searchResults]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    else
        contentForThisRow = [[[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"stoneCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        // Do anything that should be the same on EACH cell here.  Fonts, colors, etc.
    }

    // Do anything that COULD be different on each cell here.  Text, images, etc.
    [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];


    return cell;
}

- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{


    [self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

    if ([self searchResults] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self setSearchResults:array];

    }

    [[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];

    if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
    {
        for (NSMutableArray *array in contentsList)
        {
            for (NSDictionary* dictionary in array)
            {
                NSString *currentstring = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSRange r = [currentstring rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                    [[self searchResults] addObject:currentstring];
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? I'm assuming it's the objectAtIndex but which one?

Revision - I have tried to change my code around a little and now I am getting the search working but no cell titles on the original view and the search results are repeating under every heading! the code I have now is:

```
- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    [self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

    if ([self searchResults] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self setSearchResults:array];
    }

    [[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];

    if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
    {
        for (NSMutableArray *array in contentsList)
        {
            for (NSDictionary* dictionary in array)
            {
                NSString *currentstring = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSRange r = [currentstring rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                    [[self searchResults] addObject:currentstring];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
        return [self.stoneSections count];
    else
       return [self.stoneSections count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.stoneSections objectAtIndex:section];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger rows;

    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
        rows = [[self searchResults] count];
    else
        rows = [[self.contentsList objectAtIndex:section] count];


    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *contentForThisRow = nil;

    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
        contentForThisRow = self.searchResults [indexPath.row];
    else
        contentForThisRow = [[[[self contentsList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"stoneCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if(mainTableView == self.mainTableView){
        cell = [mainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = self.searchResults [indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Debugging tips: 1) step through in the debugger and see where it dies; 2) log the value of the things you call `objectAtIndex:` on; if it's a string rather than an array, that's a problem; 3) set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions and let the debugger tell you where it hits an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into the same exception.  The root cause for my problem was I was referencing an key/value pair incorrectly.  At runtime, the exception "-[__NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" was being thrown.  This perplexed me for longer than I'd care to admit.  But I found the solution to my problem, and hope it can help someone else.  The code that was throwing the exception follows along with the corrected code.

The erroneous code:

```
- (void)testMyUnitTest
{
    WorldObject *worldObject;
    NSMutableDictionary *worldCoordinatesAll = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    WorldCoordinate *localWCoordinate = [[WorldCoordinate alloc] init];

    // Populate with a world coordinate object
    [worldCoordinatesAll setObject:[localWCoordinate updateWithLatitude:X2LOC Longitude:Y2LOC Altitude:0] forKey:@"OBJECT 2"];

    for (id objectID in worldCoordinatesAll) {
        localWCoordinate = (WorldCoordinate *)objectID;
    localWCoordinate.latitude = LATITUDE_1;     // Exception being thrown on this line
    }
}
```

The corrected code:

```
- (void)testMyUnitTest
{
    WorldObject *worldObject;
    NSMutableDictionary *worldCoordinatesAll = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    WorldCoordinate *localWCoordinate = [[WorldCoordinate alloc] init];

    // Populate with a world coordinate object
    [worldCoordinatesAll setObject:[localWCoordinate updateWithLatitude:X2LOC Longitude:Y2LOC Altitude:0] forKey:@"OBJECT 2"];

    for (id key in worldCoordinatesAll) {
        id value = [worldCoordinatesAll objectForKey:key];
        localWCoordinate = (WorldCoordinate *)value;
        localWCoordinate.latitude = LATITUDE_1;
    }
}
```

I realize that for some, this might seem like a totally obvious mistake.  But for some reason, it took me a week to see it.  So I hope it helps someone else save themsleves some time.   :-)

Answer (score 1):

To find out which line of code is responsible for an exception turn on exception breakpoints.

See for example this question ["Run > Stop on Objective-C exception" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4) for information on how to turn on exception breakpoints.

What is probably happening is that you are pulling an object out of a collection that does not have the method `objectAtIndex:`. The following line

```
[[[self searchResults]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];`
```

is probably the source of the problem. Here you try to use `objectAtIndex:` on the the result of `[[self searchResults]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]` but from what i can see in `- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm`, `[self searchResults]` only contains an array of strings. This means that you apply the method `objectAtIndex:` to an `NSString` instance which does not have that method.

Comment: what more would you need to see? I can put the whole code in but it's very very long

Comment: ok run that and it says it's breaking at this point...  if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
  contentForThisRow = [[[[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

Comment: yes that does appear to be the problem, what would I need to put to correct this as I'm not sure?

Comment: That depends on what your are trying to achieve. Do you want all search results in just one section or in different ones? You may need to check for the correct section and then just using the `indexPath.row` as the argument to `objectAtIndex:` but it really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I would like to have them in different sections so say you are searching grey, there's grey in several different sections so I would like to keep them separated

Comment: I have tried to change my code around a little and now I am getting the search working but no cell titles on the original view and the search results are repeating under every heading! the code I have now is in the edit above

Comment: Also it's crashing at this stage every time I hit cancel or try to go back in the nav bar: cell.textLabel.text = self.searchResults [indexPath.row];

Comment: Don't you mean `cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`?