# cocos2d: my APP crashes but XCode doesn't give me any crash report

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash, cocos2d-iphone, stack-trace

It used to work fine but now I get this message when loading a certain scene and then the APP crashes.

```
2012-12-01 18:33:55.104 AppName[9561:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'art1-hd.png' as texture
```

I have no idea on where to start debugging this. Is there a way to get a more precise error message to understand why this happens?

Btw, I have changed my code signing identity to developer and XCode doesn't yet give me any trace of it on the console other than the plain message above. I checked as well the device logs on the Xcode-Organizer section but no trace.

I whish there was something like in Java + Eclipse, where I could get a precise STACKTRACE of where the crash happened.

**Any suggestion on how to get a precise stacktrace (E.g. with function name generating the crash)?**

PS: I have set strip debug symbols to "NO" in DEBUG, and to "YES" in Release, but I am builing on my own test iPod and hence I think it is automatically build for "Debug" (the section says build for running and testing which is confusing as the project settings allows only debug and release). But I think the problem is not here.. but in the issues above before the PS:

EDIT: If I look into the debug navigator I don't see any stacktrace of methods, as I want, but just threads.. I need to figure out how to use the global exceptions.

Comment: If the console message is a result of an exception being thrown by cocos2d then you may get a better result by setting a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions in the Breakpoint Navigator.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: You forgot to sensor the name of your app in the Xcode activity display, and the Xcode scheme selector. ;)

Comment: Ah, that should have been 'censor'.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea on where to start debugging this.

You have the cocos2d source code. I would start there.

Search for "trying to use file" in CCSpriteFrameCache to understand what the cause of this message is (which I agree is confusing, why shouldn't you use that file?).

As for the stack trace, it's available as soon as you [add a global exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4). If the breakpoint triggers in OpenAL code make sure to set it to catch only Objective-C exceptions.

Comment: Hi Steffen, I added an EDIT whit what I get.. I don't manage to figure out how to find the method call stacktrace.