# App crashes with SIGABRT error in main.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm making a simple single-view app and it crashes as soon as it loads with a SIGABRT error in main.m.

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I am new to iOS development and was just making a simple app to keep score for a quizbowl game. I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.

Comment: you have not provided enough information for solving your problem.!

Comment: error is not in main, put a break point in your class's viewdidload and viewwill appear methods also check the IB connections

Comment: what other informatio should I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to set exceptional breakpoint: ["Run > Stop on Objective-C exception" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4)

You need to set exceptional breakpoint to break on all exceptions, then you will see exactly where your code fails. The thing that your are seeing that it breaks on main is because main is your program entry and exit point of your program so if you don't handle exceptions before you will get crash shown in that call.