# adding a scene to director cocos2d iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scene

it is my first cocos2d app I try, and I am following example from book Learning Cocos2d but it seems it refers to an older version of cocos.

I have created a scene, and in its init method I add 2 layers.

Now the tutorial says, that in my delegate.m I should add this line (to be precise change the previous one that strted the HelloWorldScene) :

```
[director_ runWithScene:[GameScene node]];
```

But I am getting an error.

The weird thing is that it does not use that code at all,but that one:

```
[director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer Scene]];
```

But if I use this, I also get an error:

```
[director_ pushScene: [GameScene node]];
```

My GameScene is here:

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene
-(id) init{
    self=[super init];
    if (self!=nil){
        BackgroundLayer *backgroundLayer=[BackgroundLayer node];
        [self addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];

        GameplayLayer *gameplayLayer=[GameplayLayer node];
        [self addChild:gameplayLayer z:5];
    }
}

@end
```

and the errors I get:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS in both cases.
```

How can I start this scene from my appdelegate?

Comment: what version of cocos2d and xcode you are using?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint in Xcode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4 Then you can tell us more about the error. EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a generic error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help!

I did use that:

```
[director_ pushScene: [GameScene node]];
```

but the actual problem is that in my GameScene init method I have forgotten to return self.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send `Scene` in pushScene method argument of director, as

```
[director_ pushScene: [GameScene scene]];
```

Comment: Yes but does it mean that my GameScene has to implement the scene method?

Comment: I think `[GameScene node]` would work fine assuming GameScene inherits from CCScene.