# Random App crashes with SIGABRT error in main.m

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4.6

I am using XCode Version 4.6 (4H127), I got random crash in main.m

Please see attached screenshots

Thanks

[image]

Debugger :

[image]

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in xcode, this post covers how to do it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961770/run-stop-on-objective-c-exception-in-xcode-4. This won't solve your problem but should point out whats wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The cause of the crash is not in main.m, but rather is propagating the exception up looking for an exception handler, and since no exception handler is found, shows main.m (the highest level in the app). [Add an exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) and the app will stop at the line of code causing the exception.

The default settings (shown below) are usually sufficient.

[image]

Comment: I  have tried this. not working!

Comment: Does the app launch (i.e., gets to the initial view controller or later) when the random crash occurs), or randomly crashes when launching the app?

Comment: randomly crashes when launching the app

Comment: Any exception/error message in the debug view? If not, if you select Continue a few times, is there an error message? Add the error message to your question if any are shown.