# Crash during starting of app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, malloc

When I ran my app I got this type of crash message:

**error for object 0xd280010: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug**

I dont know how to debug this type of error. Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**

Got Error Here:

```
+ (void)runRequests
{
    // Should keep the runloop from exiting
    CFRunLoopSourceContext context = {0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CFRunLoopSourceCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &context);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    BOOL runAlways = YES; // Introduced to cheat Static Analyzer
    while (runAlways) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 1.0e10, true);//in this line i got error
        [pool drain];
    }

    // Should never be called, but anyway
    CFRunLoopRemoveSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRelease(source);
}
```

Comment: Do what the message states.

Comment: to know in which line app is crashing follow this ... on the left panel of Xcode you can see breakpoint option at the top. go to it now at the bottom you can see "+" button click on it and select "Add allexecption breakpoint". this will help you to know in which line app crashes. only thing you have to do is enable breakpoint

Comment: if you know in which line app crashes it will be easy to fix it

Comment: I have comment in my code at line which is crashing

Answer (score 0):

you are using free() or dealloc() on some object which is not allocated.
basically you have issues with memory management.
Share some code or check your self by commenting the lines where you are releasing the memory.

Comment: but I am using ARC in my app and I have used some library ASIHTTPRequest...for which I have ignore ARC so may be there can be this issue

Comment: have you tried putting exception breakpoint, at which line its crashing.

Comment: no but i dont know where to put exception breakpoint

Comment: check steps from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6208392/2450704

Comment: see my updatees parser...I have set exception break point and Got error in that code. I am not getting this error every time. It is happening sometimes only

Comment: this error is causing because of asihttprequest, you might trying to send multiple request without waiting for the first one to complete on same instance. Please check by commenting your asihttp requests.